# Como passar um parâmetro do laravel para o jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Bem, tenho um botão que ao ser clicado deverá abrir uma outra página, carregando via Ajax os resultados do banco. O problema é que tenho que passar um id por esse botão para a requisição Ajax. Fazendo uma analogia é como se fosse um botão que carregaria uma página com todos os comentários de um artigo. O id que devo passar é o id do artigo. No Ajax pego esse id do artigo e mando para o meu controller do laravel fazer a consulta e retornar o Json.
Exemplo do botão:

```
 <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="/projeto/fazer" data-id="{{$artigo->id}}" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Fazer</a>
</div>
```

Exemplo de como estou carregando o resultado via ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var artigo_id =  $(this).data('id'); //esse ID que quero receber do botão

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/carrega/comentarios/artigo/' + artigo_id,
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
    },
    success: function (data) {



        for (var i =0; i<data.length;i++){.........
```

Comment: A sua pergunta é muito ampla, tente colocar o trecho do código ao qual teve dificuldade.

Comment: Coloque techo do código HTML e Javascript do botão e dos eventos

Comment: Boa noite postei um exemplo do código.

Comment: O js esta em um arquivo separado.

Answer (score -1):

Deste jeito você não vai pegar o id. Você não está fazendo referência à tag `<a>`.

Faça assim:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="/projeto/fazer" data-id="{{$artigo->id}}" class="btn btn-default btn-article"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Fazer</a>
</div>
```

Dentro do document.ready:

```
$('a.btn-article').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // previnir da página ser carregada
    var artigo_id = $(this).data('id');
});
```

Lembrando que poder colocar a url no href também. Dai passaria a url inteira no ajax:

```
$(this).prop('href');
```

Answer (score -3):

```html
 <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="/projeto/fazer" id="btn_id" data-id="{{$artigo->id}}" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Fazer</a>
</div>


E recupera dessa forma:

$(document).ready(function() {

var artigo_id =  $('#btn_id').attr('data-id').val(); //Aqui vai recuperar o ID

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/carrega/comentarios/artigo/' + artigo_id,
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
    },
    success: function (data) {
```